# Cant push new view from Ext.navigation.View [object Window] has no method 'up'

Tags: extjs, navigation, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, push

I'm getiing this error while pushing.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'up'
```

My Code

```
Ext.define('Proj.view.test.Home', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'homeTabItem',
    id: 'home',

    requires : [],
    config: {
        refs:{
            homeTab:'homeTabItem'
        },
        title : 'Home',
        iconCls: 'home',
        scrollable:true,
        listeners  : {
            element  : 'element',
            scope : this,
            delegate : 'div',
            tap      : function(e) {
                e.stopEvent();
                console.log(e.target.id);
                this.up('homeTabItem').push({
                        xtype: 'newView'

                 });
            }
        }
    },

    initialize:function(){
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'test.html',
            method: 'GET',
            callback: function(options, success, response) {
                Ext.ComponentQuery.query('homeTabItem')[0].setHtml( response.responseText );
            }
        });
    }

})
```

Comment: Does this.up('homeTabItem') return the navigation view ?

Comment: It should. but here I'm getting nothing

Comment: got it now 'this' gives      Window {displayTabbar: true, cartItemsCount: 0, var: Object, top: Window,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create global variable

```
var myThis;
```

in initialize   add `myThis=this;`

now you can use myThis  for pushing view